# Make a column the max of another +1 PL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I cant use auto increment in phpmyadmin for this but I would like to see if its possible and find a way to get the max(displayorder) +1 every time there's a row insert. Could someone show me how this is done if it's possible? I am using mysql.

Comment: Could you explain what this has to do with PL/SQL?

Comment: Because you could make a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: Guyver: PL/SQL is a programming language developed by Oracle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL It's try that MySQL has stored procedures but I doubt they are actually written in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why can't use auto_increment?**

This should work.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (displayOrder, someColumn, someColumn)
SELECT sq.displayOrder, someValueToBeInserted, someValueToBeInserted
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(displayOrder) + 1 AS displaOrder
  FROM yourTable
) AS sq
```

but be aware that it is unreliable.